# Apple Application Loader - How to change the Apple ID being used?

Tags: iphone, ipad, app-store-connect

I want to switch the Apple ID being used by the Apple App Loader.

I can't find a way to change the Account to be used in the App itself. Google search did not bring anything useful up. When i start the Loader App it gives me an error: "...Your Apple ID or password was entered incorrectly. (-20101)" I then can only choose "cancel" in the dialogue and this is it.

Context:
I need this because the password of the Apple ID i was using previously has been changed and is not available to me anymore. This is because i was using the Admin Level Apple ID of my client in the past. Since my client decided he doesn't want to give away his admin account information any longer i need to make Application Loader use a different login (which i already have and which is working fine in iTunes connect)

Looking forward to get *any* hints on how this could be resolved. Cheers.

Comment: @pnuts lmao. just came across here again. and you seriously had to edit it 5 years later and it actually looks like it is 0% changed. would love to see the diff. feels like you are an editor for life taking no prisoners. hahaha.

Comment: @pnuts i apologize, that makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Did you try using Window -> Run Setup Wizard (shift+cmd+S) from the App Loader bar?

Answer (score 1):

In Application Loader version 2.7 and after, you need

1) Click **Window**

2) Choose **Sign In As...**