# How to add iPhone to two computers with two apple IDs

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-provisioning

Here is my situation. I have an old Mac that I used in the past to do iOS development under my personal apple ID. Now I am working at a new company and using a new Mac. I am using a new Apple ID on this new Mac. This new company has a company account on the iOS developer portal - obviously this is different from my old personal account.

I am trying to add my iPhone to my new company account so I can download/test/develop some of the apps at the new company. But it does not seem that I am able to get the provisioning profiles to work on my new company mac. I saw a suggestion to export my old mac team information to my new mac, but my new mac only shows one team (my new company team) so it isn't clear to me what to do. I want to be able to continue development on my old mac and my new mac. How exactly can I do that?

My old Mac uses XCode 4.5. My new mac uses XCode 4.6

Answer (score 0):

I have worked with 5 different provisioning accounts at once on my mac mini.  It shouldn't matter with one mac is doing relative to the other.

I'd recommend that from your new mac, you follow the directions from Apple's developer site to request a new certificate and provisioning profile for your personal account.

You may have to do a few things to get it to work.  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9890186/793607) mentions that you may need to manually edit your xcode file to get the right developer program, although I've not had this problem.